# I can't load my own CSS file when using Boostrap "MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type"

Tags: html, css, express

I'm building a personal website, and I got an error in chrome that reads:

"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

But everything seems to be linked just fine. I'm using Express, EJS, and Bootrap. I have this line in my Express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));
```

And I linked my style sheelt like normal:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"
```

I don't know what could be causing this issue. I don't have anything inside of the actual css file, and it is in the main directory with everything else.

[image: my error]

Answer (score 0):

I think the css file is not found on your server so when your server searches for the css file and it doesn't finds it.It returns back with html MIME type.

You can also import your css file in App.js component

```
import './css/styles.css';
```

Or Just change  'href' to 'src'.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="./css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. So, I changed href to src instead. The error went away, but my styles still aren't being applied. I also read that this isn't the best thing to do. Any other suggestions?